# java boolean from php website

Tags: java, php

i want to create license system in java.

I created function to check if license is true.

My code:

```
    private static boolean isPurchased(String license)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://mineverse.pl/haslicense.php?license=" + license);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        return Boolean.valueOf(str);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and chceck function onenable

```
        if(this.isPurchased(license)){ 
                    String license = cfg.getString("Licensing_System.License");
        System.out.println("Licencja" + license + " kupiona! Dziekujemy!");
        System.out.println(this.isPurchased(license));

    }else {
        System.out.println("Licencja zostala sfalszowana! Zglaszam to do serwera autoryzacji!");
    }
```

And my link:

http://mineverse.pl/haslicense.php?license=diverse12345

as you can see this link return true, (i did echo 'true';) but java console always return false (i want true because website have true at this link) and it logs:

Licencja zostala sfalszowana! Zglaszam to do serwera autoryzacji!

Whats wrong? How can i return true on my website to allow java learn this boolean?>

Comment: Debug the code to find out what `str` really contains. Does it maybe contain spaces or a newline after the text `true`? For `Boolean.valueOf(...)` to return `true`, `str` must contain 4 characters `true` and nothing else (no spaces, etc.).

Comment: oh its true on website but its returns "false" @Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your server is not just returning True or False. It is returning this instead:

```
<html>
</html>
            True
```

and your code is only reading the first line `<html>` and parsing it as a boolean, which results in false.

To fix it, either read the whole body looking for True/False or return just True/False on your body.

The following code should work with the current html even if it contains the `<html>` tags:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://mineverse.pl/haslicense.php?license=" + license);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str = null;
        boolean ret = false;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str = str.toLowerCase();
            if (str.contains("true")) {
                ret = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        return ret;
```

Comment: Can you send me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your link http://mineverse.pl/haslicense.php?license=diverse12345 and it returns this:

> <html>
>
> </html>
>
> ```
>           True
> ```

When you pass that to `Boolean.valueOf(...)`, the result will be `false`. The method `Boolean.valueOf(...)` will only return `true` if the string you pass it consists of exactly four characters: `true`.

You need to get rid of the HTML tags, the spaces and newlines, and case is also important; `True` will not work, it must be `true`.

Comment: Can you help me with this? Imreally new, how can i return that true?

Comment: i need to add i did this in echo in php.